# Is it posible to compare a variable to two accumalated database fields in a django query?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-filter

I am trying to filter the results of a django query according to a given end and start time. In my model I have a start time and duration for every database entry. I give the function the parameters endTime and startTime

What I would like is to have a filter that checks if the given endTime is smaller than the start time + duration given in the database row, so something like the following query:

```
query = Results.objects.filter(
            r_timeStart__gte=startTime,
            (F('r_timeStart') + F('r_duration'))__lte=endTime)
```

This obviously does not work. Now is my question: is it possible to compare a variable to two accumalated database fields in a django query?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to create an `annotate` field and use that in the filter.

```
query = Results.objects.annotate(current_time=F('r_timeStart') + F('r_duration'))
.filter(r_timeStart__gte=startTime, current_time__lte=endTime)
```

[Filtering on annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations)

[Annotation and Aggregation in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That worked like a charm. However, there were some more problems because I wanted to add a duration(interval) to a datetime. I could solve it with this thread though: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24485

Comment: @cyrion1000 problem with the query or the values?